# Formatted XML output in CXF?

Tags: java, xml, cxf, jax-rs

I know about the possibility how to turn on the formatting when using Marshaller. But I'm using Apache CXF (JAX-RS) and returning a response like `return Response.ok(entity).build();`.

I haven't found any option how to format the output. How can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, the way to get formatted output of XML is to set the right property on the marshaller (typically JAXB when working with CXF, which is OK since JAXB does a creditable job). That is, somewhere you're going to have something doing this:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
```

The issue is that you don't necessarily want to have *all* output formatted; it adds quite a bit to the overhead. Luckily, you're already producing an explicit `Response`, so we can just use more features of that:

```
Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(entity.getClass()).createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(entity, sw);

return Response.ok(sw.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).build();
```

---

Another method is mentioned in [this JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3861) (itself closed, but that's not so much of an issue for you):

> The workaround is to register a custom output handler which can check whatever custom query is used to request the optional indentation:

> http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/systests/jaxrs/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/jaxrs/FormatResponseHandler.java

> JAXBElementProvider and JSONProvider are driven by the JAXB Marshaller so by default they check a Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT property on the current message.

This leads to code like this:

```
public class FormattedJAXBInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    public FormattedJAXBInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        message.put(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    public void handleFault(Message message) {
        message.put(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

The CXF site [discusses registration of interceptors](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html#Interceptors-Addinginterceptorsthroughconfiguration).

Comment: I wrote above that I knew about this option. I wanted to avoid this because passing an entity to `Response.ok(entity)` does the marshalling automatically. Are you saying that this manual piece of code is the only way how to force the formatting and there is no way how to pass this to the ResponseBuilder?

Comment: Well, you could try registering a `MessageBodyWriter<Whatever>` bean that encodes the above trickiness. Then you could simply return the `Whatever`, just like with standard serialization. I've never been too keen on doing that for generating XML (too close to the default serialization engine) but it might well work in this case. A possible down-side is that *all* returned values of that type will be serialized that way (unless you add some keying off a custom annotation, I suppose)…

Comment: Also see http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Formatting-binding-output-Json-amp-Xml-td565786.html but I don't know how relevant that is to CXF 2.5…

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I was able to set a different `Marshaller` property (`JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION`) via the same technique. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a `MessageBodyWriter`.  This is a JAX-RS mechanism that allows you to override how an object is marshalled to XML.

```
package org.example;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class FormattingWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Object>{

    @Context
    protected Providers providers;

    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    public void writeTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
        OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
        WebApplicationException {
        try {
            ContextResolver<JAXBContext> resolver 
                = providers.getContextResolver(JAXBContext.class, mediaType);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext;
            if(null == resolver || null == (jaxbContext = resolver.getContext(type))) {
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
            }
            Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            m.marshal(object, entityStream);
        } catch(JAXBException jaxbException) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(jaxbException);
        }
    }

    public long getSize(Object t, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

Below is a link to a complete example where a `MessageBodyWriter` is used as part of a JAX-RS service.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Comment: That [won't work](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Registeringcustomproviders) as written with CXF, for subtle reasons. You have to manually register providers with the server bean. This is useful if you want to have different serialization strategies for different parts of the webapp, which turns out to be a *very* good thing! (I had an app which wanted to serialize POJOs to XML in several different ways — sometimes plain, sometimes with extra wrapper elements — and being able to split serialization strategy by master resource made it work.)