# Returning XML object through jax-rs

Tags: rest, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS web service which looks like so:

```
@Path("/status")
@Produces("application/xml")
@GET
public PrecisionStatus getPrecisionValue(){
    PrecisionStatus status = ...

    return status;
}
```

Initially, the result was:

```
<PrecisionStatus sensorID="TemperatureSensor5"><condition>OK</condition><fieldValue>60.0</fieldValue></PrecisionStatus>
```

It looks fine, but I want to declare the xsd file which describes this document. By using JAXB marshalling features, I was able to produce (in logger/console) the desired output:

```
<PrecisionStatus sensorID="TemperatureSensor5" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://mysite.com/myapp/xsd0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <condition>OK</condition>
    <fieldValue>60.0</fieldValue>
</PrecisionStatus>
```

(this is confirmed by unmarshalling the object).

However, if i return this object `return status;`, the browser receives the former xml document, namely the one without the reference to xsd.

I am pretty sure that the object has the right form, but somewhat the reference to xsd is stripped in the final result. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a JAX-RS `MessageBodyWriter` to have access to the `Marshaller` in order to set the `JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION` property.  For a complete example see:

- [Formatted XML output in CXF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153306/formatted-xml-output-in-cxf/10157377#10157377)