# Spring MVC calling webservice endpoint from the browser

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jaxb

I want to be able to call my web service directly from the browser. Calling it from a HTTPClient via the web browser is OK, but if i try and call it directly via the browser I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Could not instantiate JAXBContext for class [class com.mycompanay.MyClass]: 8 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 8 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.mycompany.MyInterface is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        com.mycompany.myInteface
        at private java.util.List com.mycompanay.MyClass.values
        at com.mycompanay.myClass
@XmlAttribute/@XmlValue need to reference a Java type that maps to text in XML.
    this problem is related to the following location:
```

I've tried to reference the implmentation class via the @XMLElement annotation but i'm getting the same error:

```
public MyClass {
    @XmlElement(type=MyInterfaceImpl.class, name="values")
    private List<MyInterface> values;

    @XmlElement(type=MyInterfaceImpl.class, name="values")
    public void getValues() {
    return values;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct to use the `@XmlElement` annotation to specify the implementation type.  The problem is still occurring because by default JAXB will treat public properties as mapped.  This is why it is still trying to process the interfaces.  Since you have annotated tr field you can add `XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` to your class.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html

Comment: Thanks it works but it returning XML, how can I tell it to return JSON?

Comment: @user86834 - The following may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882082/rest-json-web-services-java-ee-framework/3891380#3891380

Comment: Thanks, useful links. Just one more thing, is there anyway to retun pretty JSON?

Comment: @user86834 - The following should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153306/formatted-xml-output-in-cxf/10157377#10157377